# iPad's Apple ID did not reflect the change I made on and now I can't turn off Find my iPad

Tags: ipad, email, apple-id, password

So this is quite a headache already. I'll lay out what I've done chronologically:

- Not knowing that the Apple ID is still in use on a device (iPad), I've changed the associated email address on the Apple ID website.
- The Apple ID is now associated with the new email address
- I completely forgot this ever took place.
- The boss approaches me, asks for the password of the Apple ID.
- I forgot the password, so I reset.
- No email came through
- Checking Safari for saved password, found it.
- Did not work
- Found a similar password associated with a different email address
- Suddenly remembered the change of ID

Now, for the questions:

- Why didn't the iPad reflected the change I made regarding the email? This could've solved my problem, but it became stuck with basically a non-existent Apple ID.
- Why can't I add the old email address as an alternative, or re-associate it with the Apple ID?
- What do I do next? The iPad is associated with a non-existent Apple ID, and I can't turn off the Find my iPhone.

I hold you can help me with this issues.

Comment: If you can still get into your iCloud control panel, you can disable it from there  
https://www.icloud.com/#find

Comment: I can't. I've disabled it using the iCloud with the new email address, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: This (the above reply) worked for me, iPad on 8.4.1. Finally! Thank you. I did it a bit differently. I logged out of my old yahoo-based Apple ID in Settings/Messages (turn off iMessage), logged in under the new gmail-based Apple ID, went to Settings/iCloud which was still stuck on my yahoo-based email, signed out, and deleted my data using my gmail-based password to sign out. This is where it always failed before since I didn't have the yahoo-based password. Apparently, changing the Messages account is the key, as trying to sign out of iCloud always failed for me before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through this mess, almost the exact same steps (minus the boss asking). In my case I had forgotten about the iPad being logged in to the same account and did not turn off findMyiPhone on it before changing the appleId.

What worked for me finally, I found [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts5223) apple's KB.

Log out of iMessage on the iPad, and the log back into iMessage making sure to use the NEW appleId email address.  Next go to settings and turn off FindMyiPhone, you will be prompted for a password and the old appleid will still be displayed in the request, use the password for new appleid that you just used to log in iMessage, and it will turn off find my iphone.

Once find my iPhone is off, you can log out the account completely, and update the email address.

Comment: This is not working for me. There's a new iCloud Terms and Conditions thingy that I suspect is making all of this not work out for me. Do you think that's it?

Comment: i just did this, but it was before ios8, I didn't get it to work the first time I tried, but I was tired, and I think did the exact same thing the second time, but it worked right off second time around.

Comment: I'll try it again. The words "before ios8" made me worrisome though, because the boss updated it to 8.0.2.

Comment: There is always the second method posted at the link, Change the AppleId back temporarily.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction, and I feel like it would work given that I don't have the special case of being updated to iOS8 and having that terms and agreement prompt making my attempts futile. My boss ended up bringing it to an Apple Store to get it fixed. Still, I'll mark your answer correct. Thanks for the time.