# turn off find my iphone without apple ID password

Tags: apple-id, find-my-iphone

I need to restore my iphone, to do that i need to turn off find my iphone but the apple ID is different to the one i use now, i cant remember the password

Comment: I've never seen a phone ask for the Apple ID to turn it off, typically it will ask for the Apple ID when you turn it back on.  Also, if you've activated iCloud on this phone, it won't matter if you restore it or not, it will continue to be locked to the Apple ID that was logged into iCloud previously, even after restoring it.

Comment: see my answer to [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147483/ipads-apple-id-did-not-reflect-the-change-i-made-on-and-now-i-cant-turn-off-fi/147544) question also.

Comment: @Fyrefly Attempting to disable Find My iPhone in settings will ask for the iCloud password immediately before disabling.

Answer (score 2):

This question will likely get put on hold as a dup soon, but the best answer is really one I gave to [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147483/ipads-apple-id-did-not-reflect-the-change-i-made-on-and-now-i-cant-turn-off-fi/147544).

I had forgotten about the iPad being logged in to the same account and did not turn off findMyiPhone on it before changing the appleId.

What worked for me finally, I found [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts5223) apple's KB.

Log out of iMessage on the iPad, and the log back into iMessage making sure to use the NEW appleId email address. Next go to settings and turn off FindMyiPhone, you will be prompted for a password and the old appleid will still be displayed in the request, use the password for new appleid that you just used to log in iMessage, and it will turn off find my iphone.

Once find my iPhone is off, you can log out the account completely, and update the email address.

Edit to add: re-reading the question... you might just need to know about https://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible after iOS 7...

But you have google and the apple support : http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2702